# active directory setup for 2 vm for developments

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, java, ntlm

I don't know much about ActiveDirectory and here is my scenario

1. I am connected to a "real" domain, which my company's domain.
2. I am trying to develop an NTLM authentication solution with my webapp
   using Java Active Directory integration http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html,
3. so I figure I need to have an ActiveDirectory that I can fully control, the "virtual" one.
4. I installed Windows 2008 Server R2 on Virtual box, running as domain controller.
5. At this point, I thought I need to create another VM, say Windows7 VM which authenticates against that "virtual" ActiveDirectory, and where I will do my development.

Do I really need to do step 5 above? And what's the easiest way to do this?
I have ActiveDirectory Lightweigth Services running on my physical box, and I think it does not help in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest - in terms of keeping your test AD away from the company's AD (which I recommend) - would be to do step #5, and keep those VMs on a private virtual LAN within VirtualBox.  It's optional whether or not you configure VBox allow those VMs to make connections to he host (your physical box) - but the VMs should function as expected otherwise.